# Created a child theme but items are missing?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I setup a site to use a news theme. I already set up the site with content such as a logo in the header for example, etc. I then realized I needed to change some content and css so i set up a child theme as it says in the codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

The problem is when i activate the child theme, the logo is the placeholder logo that came with the theme and not the one i uploaded. In addition the css looks messed up. As per the documentation this is whats in my child themes styles.css

```
 In the newstheme-child/styles.css that i created
 /*
  Theme Name:     News Theme Child
  Template:       newstheme
 */

@import url("../newstheme/style.css");
```

Thats all I changed. Is there other configuration I need to setup? Or is there certain files I need to copy to the child folder?

Also will management of the theme in the admin work as it did before; such as moving page elements?

EDIT:
It looks like the problems exist in the header and footer.

*Additional note is that there are no customizations*

Comment: I know it might not sound to bright, but have you checked in the parent theme style.css to make sure that the template name is newstheme?

Comment: I'm not getting an error when i activate the theme. Also the content/css kind of looks the same but things are "off". Like the logo is the themes default and some of the navigation bars are wrapping incorrectly. It's as if the css is partially working. It's not browser cache either...

Comment: I see your theme is premium... I can't check it, 1st of all make sure it's updated, 2: themes might have some images a little hard coded (when you activate the child theme, it doesn't have the images where the theme is looking for them): try to copy the support files in the child theme (img folder, maybe js and css folders if any - only the folders and their content no files from the theme root folder) and check again, else you could also check some tutorials on the theme support site (at this point is sound to be theme specific)

Comment: I copied images, css and js without much luck. Support hasn't got back to me yet. :-/

Comment: can you start fresh and create the child theme (only the css file with the child theme details + import link) to check if there are issues with css at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was hard coded logic in the header and footer of the theme where it was loooking for relative paths. Thus the child theme being one level down in the directory does not work. The fix is to change the parent theme or hard code into the child theme.

In my case I changed the theme out with a better written one, using the [pagelines](http://www.pagelines.com/) framework. It is a wordpress framework built on child themes and the pro dev version allows multisite; which is what I am using. This solved my issue.